# Java Embed Activity in BPEL sharing instance

Tags: java, soa, bpel

I am creating a process in BPEL (say findRules) which has three Java Embeded Activity(A,B,C). and I have one java class(Rule.java) which I need to import on all Java Embed Activity.

and when I create an instance of Rule.java A activity, can I use the same instance in B and C activity. 
because I am performing some business logic in A and wanted to access the updated varibles in B and C. but because B and C are having new instance I am not able to find those updated variables.

Comment: please don't flag your question with "urgent": your question isn't more important than other people's questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are Oracle SOA suite, there is a way to do this, albeit a very dirty one. The old WLI tags are still available. **Note that this will remove portability of your code.**
`<jpd:javacode xmlns:jpd="http://www.bea.com/wli/jpd" >
public void f() {
    LOGGER.log("Some log statement");
}
</jpd:javacode>`

Then, you could use this Java method `f()`, and the same way as in wli (Using `jpd:node` and `jpd:methodName` tags)

Comment: Thanks for this update, Will you please refer me some sample or example, so that I can implement the same code in my application

Answer (score 0):

Java Embedded Activities are not part of the BPEL standard, so without knowing which BPEL tooling you use it is impossible to give an appropriate answer. However, from a design point of view, I would guess that a middleware vendor would better isolate such activities. BPEL processes are typically meant to be executed in a long-running fashion and are able to survive hardware and software crashes. Making java objects visible to certain activities would IMO break these concepts.

Comment: I am using Jdeveloper 11.1.1.3.0 and SOA 11.1.1.3.0. please let me know if any possible solution is there.

Comment: As I said, I would avoid shared Java variables and would instead use BPEL and externals services to encapsulate business logic. BPEL is designed to support long-running processes and be available and scalable. This means, if the server crashes, typically a BPEL engine is capable to resume at the point where teh crash occurred. However, if you use shared Java variables, I doubt the BPEL engine is capable to restore its value as well. Thus, my advise is always to avoid java activities in BPEL as I consider this a hack.