# share a object in all java embed activities in BPEL process

Tags: jdeveloper, bpel

Is there any way we can share a object in all java embed activities in BPEL process.

case is My BPEL process has 5 JavaEmbed Activities. at first Activity I am creating some Value Object based on some logic, and I want to use the same Value Object on Java Embed Activity 5.

value object may be many instance of same class(3 objects of Employee class)

please tell me how can I achieve the same.

My Environment is Oracle SOA 11g, Jdeveloper.

thks

Comment: Isn't that the same question as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662799/java-embed-activity-in-bpel-sharing-instance ?

Comment: Yes Sir, this is the same. but I completely messed aroung a problem and trying to get some solution. so just changing the language of question and expecting may I get some solution for workaround.

Answer (score 0):

In your first embed use setVariableData function to save the object to a variable you have created.

In your final embed use getVariableData function to retrieve your object.

Comment: Yes Sir thanks, I did the same thing. but in my case many of the business logic are implemented in value objects array. Now I have implemented logic in JavaEmbed itself...